# How to set HTMLEditorExtender HTML from client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I cannot get this to work, here is code that I found in another thread but it is not working for me, I'm getting "set_content is not a function" :

```
$find("<%=Hee.ClientID%>").set_content("whatever");
```

Is this still valid?
I also tried to set value of the textbox it extends, tried setting InnerHtml of both,none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$find("<%= Hee.ClientID %>")._editableDiv.innerHTML = "whatever";
```

Comment: Thanks for replay,I dropped HEE althogether because it's broken too much: size problem, auto-focus...etc. I replaced it with tiny MCE. But I guess this could work, I tried something smilar before like: $find("<%= editableDiv.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "whatever"; But that didn't work.

Comment: if you drop the find and do instead $("id").innerHTML = "it works";

Answer (score 2):

I was going nuts for hours looking for a way to change the content and here's what I've come up with that works quite well:

This is the TextBox and Extender:

```
<asp:Textbox ID="replyBody" Height="450px" Width="892px" runat="server" TextMode ="MultiLine"  />
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="replyBody_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" EnableSanitization="false" TargetControlID="replyBody">
</ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Now this is the javascript that changed the value:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    function changeText(someString){
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_replyBody_HtmlEditorExtender_ExtenderContentEditable').innerHTML = someString; 
    }
</script>
```

This works like a charm. The above element ID is actually that of a div, however changing its contents updates the `replyBody.Text` property

Comment: What is the object with id `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_replyBody_HtmlEditorExtender_ExtenderContentEditable` and how do you determine the ClientID at run time?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#<%=Hee.ClientID%>").html("whatever");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this out:

```
var ctrl = $get("<%=Hee.ClientID%>").control;
ctrl.set_content("whatever");
```

Comment: Im getting exception in firebug at "$get(" this way I assuame it's because ".control"